# What child did Harry give the Marauders Map to, if any?

Tags: harry-potter, marauders-map

The Marauder's Map was last seen in Harry's possesion during *Deathly Hallows*.

What child did Harry give the Marauders Map to, if any?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Apparently, James Sirius Potter stole it (Lived up to his name, li'l boy!)!

[ [Ref](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) ]

> **Courtney:** What child did Harry give the Marauders Map to if any
>   **J.K. Rowling:** I've got a feeling he didn't give it to any of them, but that James sneaked it out of his father's desk one day.

Comment: I wish these sort of details would have made it into the book, instead of the thrown-together ending we got :(

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for the details.

Comment: You'd think that she'd know, instead of having a feeling. They are her characters, after all.

Comment: Pfff.  My characters do things I didn't expect them to *all the time*.  If can predict their actions completely... you didn't write strong enough characters.

Comment: What a terrible thing to break such a tradition...

Answer (score 5):

According to The Cursed Child

> Harry had the map under lock at least during Albus's third year, since he was able to loan it out to Headmistress Mcgonnagall.

Comment: This was the part of the play that bothered me the most.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that he didn't give it to anyone, he just kept it as an old souvenir.

Comment: Well, [ykombinator turned up JKR's opinion on that](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3275), but it's not based on what's in the book. What, in the book, do you base your assumption on?

Comment: Please include a reference to assist in your claim.

Comment: Hope you have some basis to support your theory!!!